# Python: TypeError: unbound method insertionSort() must be called with Employee instance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Tags: python

So I can figure out what is the meaning of TypeError: unbound method insertionSort() must be called with Employee instance as first argument (got list instance instead)
Please help!

```
class Employee():    

def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary


def insertionSort(EmpList):
    for i in range (1, len(EmpList)):
        key = EmpList[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < EmpList[j]:
            EmpList[j + 1] = EmpList[j]
            j -= 1
        EmpList[j + 1] = key

 
e1 = Employee("Ada", 15000)
e2 = Employee("Brian", 18000)
e3 = Employee("Carson", 12000)
e4 = Employee("Dave", 14000)
EmpList = [e1,e2,e3,e4]
Employee.insertionSort(EmpList)
for i in range (len(EmpList)):
    print("% d" % EmpList[i])
```

Comment: Welcome (back?) to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. Also, make sure when you post your code that it appears [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), with the same indentation that your actual code has.

Comment: (It's not possible to answer this properly because the code you show would be a syntax error; what you actually have could be multiple different things, and the answer would depend on which it is.)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee():    

  def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary


  def insertionSort(EmpList):
      for i in range (1, len(EmpList)):
          key = EmpList[i]
          j = i - 1
          while j >= 0 and key.salary < EmpList[j].salary:
              EmpList[j + 1] = EmpList[j]
              j -= 1
          EmpList[j + 1] = key

 
e1 = Employee("Ada", 15000)
e2 = Employee("Brian", 18000)
e3 = Employee("Carson", 12000)
e4 = Employee("Dave", 14000)
EmpList = [e1,e2,e3,e4]
Employee.insertionSort(EmpList)
for i in range (len(EmpList)):
    print(EmpList[i].name,EmpList[i].salary)
```

You can't compare instances of Emloyee, instead I changed it "key.salary < EmpList[j].salary" so you can compare their salary

Comment: This does not address the described error, and also you are making assumptions about how the code is indented (after it was incorrectly formatted by OP).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error since you didn't add `@staticmethod` above `def insertionSort(...` [read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    @staticmethod
    def insertionSort(EmpList):
        for i in range(1, len(EmpList)):
            key = EmpList[i]
            j = i - 1
            while j >= 0 and key.salary < EmpList[j].salary:
                EmpList[j + 1] = EmpList[j]
                j -= 1
            EmpList[j + 1] = key


e1 = Employee("Ada", 15000)
e2 = Employee("Brian", 18000)
e3 = Employee("Carson", 12000)
e4 = Employee("Dave", 14000)
EmpList = [e1, e2, e3, e4]
Employee.insertionSort(EmpList)
for i in range(len(EmpList)):
    print(EmpList[i].name)
```